# Change plot data based on callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

How can I change the underlying data of a treemap based on a selection of a cell or possibly even multiple cells? For example, I select the cell containing the string "Texas" and the treemap zooms in or crops to the tile "Texas" (or I select the cells containing the strings "Texas" and "Colorado" and the treemap zooms in or crops to the tiles "Texas" and "Colorado")?

```
"""Doc."""

from dash import Dash, dcc, Input, Output, callback, dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')
# df = pd.read_csv('solar.csv')

app = Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
    )

# Treemap

fig = px.treemap(
    df,
    path=[px.Constant("all"), "State"],
    values='Number of Solar Plants'
    )

# Layout

app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Label('Click a cell in the table:'),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        df.to_dict('records'),
        [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        id='tbl'
        ),

    dbc.Alert(id='tbl_out'),

    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

])


@callback(
    Output('tbl_out', 'children'),
    Input('tbl', 'active_cell')
    )
def update_graphs(active_cell):
    print(active_cell)
    return str(active_cell) if active_cell else "Click the table"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]